# R doesnt read saved scripts

Tags: r

I installed the hsi package in R and did the updates it asked me to do, then installed the package and was able to run the codes. However when I went to open my other scripts they all came up blank, even the one I was using.

I have no idea what happened and I have no idea how to get them to open

Comment: What editor are you using, RStudio or something else? Have you looked at the script files in your operating system? Do they exist? Do they have a non-zero file size? Have you tried opening the scripts in another editor, like Notepad?

Comment: What exactly do you mean they came up blank? Are you opening them in RStudio? Or the RGUI? Are these .R files or something else? Can you check to see they have a non-zero file size? It's really not clear exactly what's going on from your description.

Comment: Yes, I opened the scripts in notepad and they were right. I decided uninstall R and R studio. Then I installed both softwares and final word. Thanks for your answers!